# Cannnot turn on "control device permission" in Anydesk on Android

Tags: remote-control

I use Anydesk software on my devices and recently I've faced a problem with controlling my Android device with my Windows machine. Once I try to connect to the Android phone through Windows, I can see the phone's screen but I can't control it. I noticed that on my phone, "control device's mouse and keyboard" permission is off and I can't turn it on.

[image: Anydesk permissions].

I've already installed the AD plugin.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The [AnyDesk plugin ad1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydesk.adcontrol.ad1) has also to be installed - activated and accepted.

Furthermore, you have to manually turn it on in Settings - Accessibility of Android - Locate 'Anydesk Control service' - turn it on.

Then you can choose full control and you will be able to access the mouse and cursor.

Answer (score 0):

how to unlock (use) the **control my device** option in any desk for Android phones?

1. install (**ADControl AD1**) from play store.
2. go to settings and search for (**Accessibility**).
3. find your installed services and click on (**AnyDesk Control services AD1**).
4. then you have to manually turn it on.

you are good to go now ^_^

Comment: On Googling, it is not obvious which app you mean.   What I am finding i scalled `Anydesk plugin AD1`, not `ADControl AD1`. Please provide a link to its home page, in your answer.